# ¿Como hacer que el toolbar se muestre por encima y no este por abajo de cada elemento de un fragment?

Tags: java, android-studio

aquí de nuevo con mi app que estoy desarrollando ya que cada vez que voy avanzando surgen algunos detalles, en esta ocasión vengo batallando ya que estoy trabajando con fragments.

La cuestión es la siguiente tengo un `fragment` que contiene `GridLayout` y `CardView` ya que tengo 10 card y solo se mostraban 6 card y para que se mostraran todas use el componente `ScrollView` pero al momento de ejecutar la aplicación todos elementos se muestran por arriba del `toolbar` y no he logrado todavía alguna solución que permita mostrar los elementos abajo del `toolbar`, también el detalle que quiero dar clic al icono de inicio no me deja o no pasa nada que me desplegué, ya que anteriormente todo este proceso lo tenia en un `activity` y ahí no tenia problemas, empece a optar por fragments ya que voy a tener muchos módulos y me dijeron que no es recomendable muchos activitys hace lento la app.

**Fragment_menu**
Aqui solo voy a agregar el código de un card para no alargar mas el tema.

```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="FragmentMenu.Menu_fragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

        <ScrollView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
           <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/informacion"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Información"
                android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
                android:textSize="22dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"/>

            <GridLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="165dp"
                android:layout_below ="@id/informacion"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:rowCount="1"
                >

                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card_volcan"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/verdeclaro">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="127dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/volcanpopoca" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="108dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Volcán Popocatépetl"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="18dp" />

              </LinearLayout>

           </ScrollView>

         </FrameLayout>
```

**content_main**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">


  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contenido"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

  </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Puedes utilizar un android:layout_marginTop asignandolo a las propiedades de tu gridLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añade el atributo `android:layout_marginTop` al XML del `Fragment`, así:

```
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
```

Tal como sugiere [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34115586/13419694) de SO.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo Mateo, me funciono tu respuesta, saludos..